# Alternative ways to quickly attach/remove a hang beam for suspension training workouts?

Tags: mounting

I've drawn few ways that straps or carabiner + straps + cam buckles could help hang a pipe from the 2 ceiling clips lag-bolted into the concrete ceiling slab.

[image]

Updated scratch work: 
[image: diagram 2]

The reason for adding the pipe is that it would allow me to do what direct strap entry does not:

- different widths at which straps can be hung
- easier faster move around, put over and removal
- allow more straps and variety of stuff to be quickly and easily removable

Would alternative (different kind of cross section) or modification (holes/ hooks) to pipe be better & give more options?

**Updated points:**  There are different ways of attaching the beam to the ceiling clips.

- If I go with Blue then I can't slide straps to full length of a longer pipe than the distance between the clips. I'll have to mount and remount straps inside vs outside of blue support. Straps outside the support straps can be simply slid off the outer end.
- If I go with Pink (closed loop) I can slide straps though entire length of beam within the pink loop, but to remove them I'll always have to fully remove the support strap.

If this would be better served by DIY we could move it there, but I'm thinking this needs only a minor hack - even though maybe DIY folks with experience with hardware might have more ideas?

Comment: Do both. Come here for the wacky, out-of-the-box lifehacks and then go to DIY to find out how it should be done properly? Whadyathink?

Comment: Putting a strap through a tube would put a lot of wear at the point where the strap rubs against the end of the tube. This would be true even if the edge was smooooth.

Comment: @Stan But in this case it appears you came up with a brilliant hack yourself and are just looking for a good and safe way to implement it. Hack: use a pipe to be more flexible with your workout gear + allow the hanging space to be used for other things = use space more efficiently. So really you should post this on DIY. On the other side it would be a pity to see the hack gone from here - the problem seems to be that the answer is in the question. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Since we're talking about something load bearing and expected to safely carry your weight, I suggest re-asking this in the context of DIY to be done properly and safely  rather than hacking together a *"how to"* on *this* site.

Comment: Any ideas on using a different cross section (instead of circular for a pipe)? Any other pros & cons? Cuts/ indentations?

Comment: I think if I can get away without having to go to DIY levels and hardware I'll probably life hack it using straps and pipe. Simpler than going full Home Depot on it (and there's no Home Depot around here to make it easy)

Comment: Why the down votes to the question? +

Answer (score 2):

Use chain to hang a horizontal bar from the clips anchored into the concrete slab ceiling. Remove the straps (or leave them on for BDSM parties) and install the chain too.

If the links of the chain permit, you can put the bar through a link on either side of the chain. If the bar is a pipe too large for putting through a link, a suitable carabiner can be used. For different heights, choose a different pair of links. You can use coloured twist-ties to mark frequently-used pairs of links.

[image]

Visit a hardware store and some old guy with tattoos wearing a blue apron and glasses will show you the right kind of chain and cut equal lengths for you. Get a couple of removable links to attach the chain to the ceiling clips. If you want fancy, you can get stainless steel chain to match your ceiling clips.

Comment: Pound for pound, nylon straps are stronger than iron chain. Tables of equivalent load bearing capability is available for various materials in different configurations. Be generous when figuring out how much weight will be supported and the inertias of the weights supported.

Comment: Ha ha! I was so workout focused that I didn't think of the BDSM angle ;) ha ha. So, even if I use chain it will only be up to the upper side as a mounting beam. My gym straps (have a few) will be my all purpose changing mechanisms. I've got a pair of polyester straps (ordered specifically) and 2 others that may be Nylon or Polypropylene (will have to check)

Comment: What if the orange and pink were one piece  closed loop? If straps, then closed via sewing or metal buckle/ carabiner. If chain, then similarly. Might avoid chain if I can find a way to soften the edge pressure on straps, maybe with a filler like foam or something?

Answer (score 0):

If you drill a hole through the pipe you could put a eye bolt through it then you could attach chain/nylon strap to the eye part. Could even put on a carabiner for quick removal.